# Java SE + Spring Data + Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I am trying to start a Java SE application with Spring Data + Hibernate and have done the follwowing till now:

**Configuration File**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:hibernate.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfiguration {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN =
            "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new
                LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(org.hibernate
                .jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.
                getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT,
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL,
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public MainBean mainBean() {
        return new MainBean();
    }
}
```

**Start class**

```
public class Start {


    private static final String CONFIG_PACKAGE = "org.app.config";


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new
                AnnotationConfigApplicationContext()) {

            ctx.scan(CONFIG_PACKAGE);
            ctx.refresh();

            MainBean bean = ctx.getBean(MainBean.class);
            bean.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Main Bean

```
public class MainBean {

        public void start() {

        System.out.println("Application Started. . .");


    }

}
```

However I'm getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\MyPath\target\classes\org\app\config\JpaConfiguration.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:281)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.scan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:220)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.scan(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:153)
    at org.app.Start.main(Start.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:257)
    ... 4 more
```

Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10292

Comment: Check out Spring Boot, it will help you eliminate almost all of the configuration you have and also import the correct versions of the dependencies http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The exception you see is not very likely to be cause by invalid Spring configuration but your classpath setup. This feels like a version incompatibility regarding the ASM libraries and Java 8. The ASM version, Spring 3.2 depends on is known to be incompatible with Java 8.

Thus, if you want run your code with Java 8, you need to use a recent Spring 4.0 version.

Comment: Thank you so much!
I've wasted several hours solving this problem

Answer (score 9):

I was also facing same issue with Spring-3.2.0 and Java 8 ( jdk1.8.0_60 ).
After using 3.2.14 release of spring framework , it works.

Comment: Actually, if the OP did indeed face a Java8 related issue, this answer is the correct answer, to get Spring 3.2 working on Java8, upgrading to latest version makes it work without any changes.