# Spring web tutorial not working with STS 3.5.1.RELEASE and Gradle

Tags: spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I've installed STS 3.5.1.RELEASE and tried to follow the web tutorial:
http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/web/
So I've installed gradle from within the STS to run the task "tomcatRunWar" on the code from section 6, as adviced in the tutorial. But I get an error and have no clue how to handle that. Here is the console output:

```
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Starting Gradle build for the following tasks: 
[sts]      tomcatRunWar
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
The ConfigurationContainer.add() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please use the create() method instead.
The TaskContainer.add() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please use the create() method instead.
PROJECT=tut-web-6-complete
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:war UP-TO-DATE
:tomcatRunWarException sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setObjectPostProcessor(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectPostProcessor' defined in class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: class path resource [com/yummynoodlebar/config/SecurityConfig.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setObjectPostProcessor(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectPostProcessor' defined in class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: class path resource [com/yummynoodlebar/config/SecurityConfig.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectPostProcessor' defined in class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: class path resource [com/yummynoodlebar/config/SecurityConfig.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:558)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: class path resource [com/yummynoodlebar/config/SecurityConfig.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1025)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:921)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:86)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1488)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: class path resource [com/yummynoodlebar/config/SecurityConfig.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: class path resource [com/yummynoodlebar/config/SecurityConfig.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:56)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:386)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:53)
    ... 62 more
Error listenerStart
Context [] startup failed due to previous errors

Started Tomcat Server
The Server is running at http://localhost:8080
```

Update:
Thanks to mserioli.
I guess I have to change the "build.gradle" file then. But how can I find out which versions to choose? Here is the original file:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'tomcat'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'propdeps'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-maven'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-idea'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'idea'

println "PROJECT=" + project.name

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url "http://download.java.net/maven/2"
    }
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release' }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-tomcat-plugin:0.9.8'
    classpath 'org.springframework.build.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.1'
  }
}


//{!begin repos}
repositories {
  mavenCentral()

  maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone/'}
}
//{!end repos}

dependencies {
  def tomcatVersion = '7.0.42'
  tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
          "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}"
  tomcat("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}") {
    exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler', module: 'ecj'
  }

  compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final'
  compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.1.Final'

  compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.3.RELEASE'
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.3.RELEASE'

  //{!begin deps}
  compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.0.M2'
  compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.0.M2'
  compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.2.0.M2'
  //{!end deps}

  compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
  runtime 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5'

  compile 'org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring3:2.0.18'

  testCompile 'org.springframework:spring-test:3.2.3.RELEASE'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
  testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
  testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3"

  provided 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
}

test {
  testLogging {
    // Show that tests are run in the command-line output
    events 'started', 'passed'
  }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = '1.6' }

tomcatRunWar.contextPath = ''
```

As alternative solution, I set the "Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> JDK Compliance -> Compiler compliance level" to 1.7 . This starts with the following console output (looks like I'm not allowed to paste the whole thing):

```
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Starting Gradle build for the following tasks: 
[sts]      tomcatRunWar
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
The ConfigurationContainer.add() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please use the create() method instead.
The TaskContainer.add() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please use the create() method instead.
PROJECT=tut-web-6-complete
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:war UP-TO-DATE
:tomcatRunWarException sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setObjectPostProcessor(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectPostProcessor' defined in class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: class path resource [com/yummynoodlebar/config/SecurityConfig.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

What else could I do?

Comment: take a look at that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730801/java-se-spring-data-hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding something like this to 'build.gradle':

```
 sourceCompatibility = 1.7
 targetCompatibility = 1.7
```

I think the problem is that you are telling the eclipse compiler to target Java 1.7, but in fact you are not using the eclipse compiler. I.e. when you run 'tomcatRunWar' task, Gradle rather than eclipse will compile and run the code.

BTW: if it works correctly then when you do 'Gradle >> Refresh All' in the IDE. Then gradle should also configure the eclipse project settings to use these compiler compatibility settings in the IDE.

The correct flow of information is to configure the build correctly and then let it configure your IDE, not the other way around.

Final warning, there is a bug [*] in the gradle eclipse plugin that it won't configure JRE classpath container. This probably won't cause a problem... but it might. If so, see linked bug report for a workaround.

[*] http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3100

Comment: Thank you @Kris ! I cannot find that 'Gradle >> Refresh All' in the IDE. But I'm already glad that it's working :)

Comment: It should be in the project context menu which you access by right-clicking on your project.