# IllegalArgumentException at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader when initializing Spring context

Tags: java, spring

Can anyone please guide me with the possible reason for the below mentioned error, being encountered while trying to execute the java spring program. The error is as follows...

```
Aug 20, 2014 4:43:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre8/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre8/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre8/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\lib;D:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\bin;D:\Softwares\Eclipse Dump\EclipseForSpring;;.
Aug 20, 2014 4:43:54 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:HelloWorld' did not find a matching property.
Aug 20, 2014 4:43:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 20, 2014 4:43:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 20, 2014 4:43:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 577 ms
Aug 20, 2014 4:43:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 20, 2014 4:43:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
Aug 20, 2014 4:43:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Aug 20, 2014 4:43:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'HelloWorld'
Aug 20, 2014 4:43:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'HelloWorld': initialization started
Aug 20, 2014 4:43:56 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'HelloWorld-servlet': startup date [Wed Aug 20 16:43:56 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 20, 2014 4:43:56 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/HelloWorld-servlet.xml]
Aug 20, 2014 4:43:57 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider registerDefaultFilters
INFO: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
Aug 20, 2014 4:43:57 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:600)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:519)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:460)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Aug 20, 2014 4:43:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:600)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:519)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:460)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Aug 20, 2014 4:43:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /HelloWorld threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:600)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:519)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:460)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Aug 20, 2014 4:43:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 20, 2014 4:43:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 20, 2014 4:43:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2186 ms
```

My Server Files as are as follows:
server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>

      <Context docBase="HelloWorld" path="/HelloWorld" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:HelloWorld"/></Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

tomcat-users.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user password="SmarTec@123" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui" username="root"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>fork</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: what's your spring and jdk version

Comment: spring 3.1.0 and jdk 1.7

Comment: Have a look here it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730801/java-se-spring-data-hibernate

Comment: You **ARE** using JDK 8, have a look in the logs: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\bin". So, try Spring 4 with JDK 8, or use JDK 1.7.

Comment: You might be correct Andrei, i have both jdk 1.8 and jdk 1.7 installed on my computer. But in my current project in eclipse i have referenced only jdk 1.7 only and opted out jdk 1.8 Do you wish to say that, still jdk 1.8 is in reference and i have to uninstall jdk 1.8

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring context initialization failed with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException while deploying to Apache 7.0.54 and java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24128045/spring-context-initialization-failed-with-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-whi)

Comment: and what does that mean, what do i need to do?????? @M.Deinum

Comment: Just perform a simple test: use Spring 4 instead of 3 in your app and see how it goes.

Comment: @VishalJain Read the accepted answer. Either use JDK 1.7 or use Spring4. Spring 3 doesn't work with JDK 1.8. (Although you might get lucky with 3.2.9 or up).

Comment: what if i need to stick to jdk 1.7, please guide me what shall i do???

Comment: How do you run your project? In Eclipse, outside it?

Comment: jumping to spring 4 can be an option, let me try first.....

Comment: I run it in eclipse and use 'run as server' option from the toolbar

Comment: also I have not yet introduced hibernate in my project

Comment: Ok. Double click on your Tomcat Server definition in Eclipse. Under "General Information" go to "Runtime Environment" and click on it. In the window that opens you have a field "JRE" that will tell you which JRE your Tomcat will run with.

Comment: It was jre8 and i switched back to jre7 but still getting error. `Launching Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost (2) has encountered a problem.   Several Ports(8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost (2) are already in use`. But my Apache Tomcat Service is already stopped.

Comment: So, you were using JRE 8. The new error is something else that has nothing to do with the question you posted initially. Most probably you have another Tomcat running (maybe inside Eclipse itself).

Comment: You are right... But how do i stop it??? In the 'Edit Launch configuration properties' of the Tomcat server when I choose `Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost (2)` it says `Server already running`. Please guide me on that.

Comment: From the Servers View: Window menu -> Show view -> Servers.

Comment: Did  as you said. The server Stopped. and Still upon execution the error remains the same `Launching Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost (2) has encountered a problem.   Several Ports(8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost (2) are already in use.`

Comment: You need to show some willingness to fix this and try to research this, as well. You can't just wait a step-by-step list of instructions on any small issue you have. Not to mention that this discussion has nothing to do with the issue you described initially in the post.

Comment: The Error past, server status still says `Stopping` and it won't stop. and even the option of `Stop` shows disabled. I wonder Why????

Comment: Restart STS and be done with it. If it won't restart, kill it.

Comment: Sorry about that, But I am actually new to this configuration and not getting much Idea as in what to do... Do you need me to coin a new question????

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The probable answer to the original question shall be that switching to JRE7 from JRE8 might help. As in my case the error message Changed. So this shall be considered as an option while using Spring 3.1.0. It helped me.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using JRE 8 then change your spring version to 4. It will work perfectly..

Answer (score 2):

To be exact, if you not using Maven (like me), I just update the:

```
spring-core-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar
```

to Version 4, then it solves my problem. The rest of other spring Jars, I leave it the same.