# Unable to create ThreadPoolExecutor from Spring application context

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am getting *IllegalArgumentException* while creating a ThreadPoolExecutor in the following way.

```
<bean id="processorQueue" class="java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque"/>
<bean id="processorThreadPool" class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="int" value="10"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" type="int" value="20"/>
        <constructor-arg  type="long" value="1"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <value type="java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit">MINUTES</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg ref="processorQueue"/>
</bean>
```

What am I doing wrong?
(I am using Spring 3.2 with Java 8)

This is the stack trace.

```
2015-08-10 14:20:14  DefaultListableBeanFactory doGetBean  [http-nio-8080-exec-37] DEBUG: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'processorQueue'
2015-08-10 14:20:14  DispatcherServlet initServletBean  [http-nio-8080-exec-37] ERROR: Context initialization failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.inspectClass(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:110)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1017)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have tried with passing same value for corePoolSize and maximumPoolSize but the result is same.

Comment: your code worked fine in my web application, i have used java 7, spring 4.0

Comment: are you using java 8 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730801/java-se-spring-data-hibernate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From JavaDoc (1.8) I can see the following:

```
@throws IllegalArgumentException if one of the following holds:<br>
{@code corePoolSize < 0}<br>
{@code keepAliveTime < 0}<br>
{@code maximumPoolSize <= 0}<br>
{@code maximumPoolSize < corePoolSize}
```

I added your extract to one of my apps and it worked fine unless I changed the parameters to violate one of the conditions above and therefore forcing an IllegalArgumentException. The order of the parameters is the same since Java 1.5 so your config should work. Can you maybe provide the stack trace when starting your app?

Comment: Dennis, please check the stack trace.

Comment: I've tried this with Java 8 and Spring Context 3.2.14.RELEASE. It's still working. As described by http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/migration-3.2.html, I didn't add any ASM dependency directly. Apart from context, do you have any other spring dependencies on your classpath and are you using the latest, quite recent 3.2.14 versions?

Comment: Oh, I was using 3.2.2.RELEASE. It is working perfectly with 3.2.14.RELEASE. Great Help, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you have not mentioned your classpath setup, but seems that your are using java 8 with spring 3.2 which doesn't support it. upgrade spring to 4.0

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes, I am using Java 8. I'll check with 4.0.